# Table of Contents does not show up when compiled over console

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to complile a .tex documents on my server, so I tried to use the pdflatex command in my command line, but the Table of Contents does not work - it just doesn't show up.

When I compile the exact same document with TexWorks it works perfektly fine. Why could that be?

Thats the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Gubert Farnsworth}
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered Section}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\section{Second Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```

best
LaPlace

Comment: Did you compile (at least) twice? Many editors, like probably TeXworks, do this automatically for you, but with the console you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Wow! That's it. It just makes sense that the document must be compiled at least twice because the ToC must know where the sections are....
I feelt stupid now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually three times is better: the first time the toc file is created, which is read in the second run. But typesetting the ToC will in general move the stuff after it, so a further run is required. Two runs might work for a short ToC but three is the way to go. BTW the output _does_ tell you "Labels might have changed. Rerun."

Comment: write a `makefile` or shell script, containing the commands to compile a `*.tex` document. it'll save you time in the long run

Comment: or use `latexmk` in the console, which is written for this purpose.